# Python Django send_mail newlines?

Tags: python, django, email

I'm using django send_mail like this:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail('Test', 'asdfasdfasdf\nasdfasfasdfasdf\nasdfasdfasdf', 'sender@test.com', ['receiver@test.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Gmail recieves this.

```
Content-type: multipart/alternative; boundary="----------=_1382512224-21042-56"
------------=_1382512224-21042-56
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

asdfasdfasdf
asdfasfasdfasdf
asdfasdfasdf

------------=_1382512224-21042-56
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html><body>
<p>asdfasdfasdf asdfasfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf</p>
</body></html>
```

And shows my newlines as one whole paragraph. Why? I would like three lines of text, not one.

Comment: One solution would be to send as plain/text i guess..

Comment: change the Content-Type to text/plain or use <br/> instead of \n

Comment: The <br/> tags became like this? <p>asdfasdfasdf&lt;br/&gt;asdfasfasdfasdf&lt;br/&gt;asdfasdfasdf</p>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try sending your email as HTML instead of plain text. Use [EmailMessage()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types).

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

msg = EmailMessage(
    'Test',
    'asdfasdfasdf<br>asdfasfasdfasdf<br>asdfasdfasdf',
    'sender@example.com',
    ['receiver@example.com', ]
)
msg.content_subtype = "html"
msg.send()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want control over the different components of the mutlipart e-mail, you can create a `EmailMultiAlternatives` and then `.send()` the email message you created.

Django's exmample from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types).

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'from@example.com', 'to@example.com'
text_content = 'This is an important message.'
html_content = '<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```